# How can I have a mysql primary key never be repeated even after it's been deleted

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I inherited a pretty poorly designed mysql database where there are no true foreign keys between say a user table and a preferences table.

Consider

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'email address',
  ...
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `preference` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  ...
)
```

If I delete a row from the user table, this leaves the preference table orphaned. However with the above primary key in mysql, as soon as I add a new row to user table, it will actually use the old id from the previously deleted row - thus linking to the old users' preferences (very undesirable).

Despite the poor implementation (yes, I know the proper thing to do is to refactor code and update the database with true foreign key relationships), it there a way to guarantee that a primary key is never reused?

Comment: MySQL should _not_ be reusing auto increment primary keys. Unless you manually reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value, deletions should have no effect on future id values - they should just keep incrementing.

Comment: How are you adding new rows? You aren't doing something crazy like selecting `MAX(id) + 1` to get the next value are you? the `AUTO_INCREMENT` is designed to handle your situation gracefully.

Comment: I didn't think it would either, but somehow it is reusing it. It's php (ugh) code, and it does not do any sort of stupid thing like `max(id)` (whew!).

Comment: Holy ****, I found this PHP in the project (I inerited). Darn you newb programmers ;)

`function nextAutoId ($tbl)
    {
     $cq = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '{$tbl}'";
     $cqres = mysql_query($cq);
     $cqr = mysql_fetch_assoc($cqres);
     $nid = $cqr['Auto_increment'];
     return $nid;
    }`

Comment: Wow, that'll do it. I often see novice programmers attempt to reset or "fill in" the holes left by auto-inc deletions, but that misses the point. They're supposed to be _unique_ and the fact that they are an incrementing set is merely a side-effect of a simple form of uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a constraint to set as null the value of the foreign key after que record with the related primary key has been deleted. It can be achieved with the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `fk_table`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_constraint_name`
    FOREIGN KEY(`fk_field`)
    REFERENCES `pk-table` (`pk`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL
```

As said in the comments of your question, MySQL does not reuse the values from `auto_increment`.

Comment: This not trigger, but foreign key constraint. And this clause deletes child rows, no null will be used.